# Outer measure one and non-empty intersection with closed sets

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $X$ be a compact probability space whose Borel sets are measurable. I want to show that a subset $A$ of $X$ is of outer measure one if and only if $A$ has a non-empty intersection with every closed subset of positive measure.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is $X$ a metric space?

Comment: No, not necessarily